# How to get Horizontol as well as the vertical scrollbars in Android's Table Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollbar, tablelayout, tablerow

Here is my code :
What i want is just to make scrollbar available in my application so that the overflow text 
will be present in the screen.

Here i am using table layout and table row where my content is too long for a row and it will be long for height of screen so how to display horizontal and vertical scrollbar this code is not working

```
       <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeaderModels"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Demo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="8pt" />
        </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try enclosing within both the scrolls like this,

```
<ScrollView>

     <HorizontalScrollView>

                <TableLayout>

                        <TableRow>

                            //Your Elements Here

                        </TableRow>

                <TableLayout>      

     </HorizontalScrollView>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: if it is possible with table layout then its better –

Comment: yes, you have to embed your table layout within this scrolls. Else you can't do it with tableLayout alone

Comment: but there is attributes in tableLayout



 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

Comment: I dont think they can be of any use. This is how I made it work. Even I tried your way, but got no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ScrollView`. Here is the Reference link. [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Tutorial Here - http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#scrollview

Answer (score 1):

put your table layout inside a `Horizontal Scroll view`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal">


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: dude what is want both scroll view horizontol as well as vertical if it is possible with table layout then its better